# Downloading files using google-api-php-client

Tags: php, json, api, cloud, google-api-php-client

I'm having an issue trying to download a file from Google Cloud Storage using the php client found at https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/

I have authenticated myself ok and using the following code I can return an object which contains the link to my file

```
$this->storageService = new Google_StorageService($this->client);
$this->objects = $this->storageService->objects;

$options = array(
    'prefix' => 'REPORT_NAME_2013-07-01'
);
$bucket_contents = $this->objects->listObjects($bucket, $options);
```

The response is something like...

```
{

 "kind": "storage#object",
 "id": "<bucket>/<report>.csv/1001",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1beta2/b/<bucket>/o/<report>.csv",
 "name": "<report>.csv",
 "bucket": "<bucket>",
 "generation": "1001",
 "metageneration": "1",
 "contentType": "application/csv",
 "updated": "2013-07-22T10:21:08.811Z",
 "size": "806",
 "md5Hash": "wT01i....",
 "mediaLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1beta2/b/<bucket>/o/<report>.csv?generation=1001&alt=media",
 "owner": {
  "entity": "user-00b........",
  "entityId": "00b490......."
 },
 "crc32c": "8y........",
 "etag": "CPjZ.........."
}
```

But how do I go about downloading the file using the Google PHP client...I can't use a file_get_contents as it has no knowledge of the authentication details.
The best thing I have found is something that uses the Google_Client but the response simply contains meta data and no object/file content

```
$request = new Google_HttpRequest($object['selfLink']);
$response = $this->client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($request);
```

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but it got me looking in the right direction. `selfLink` is the link to the metadata request, you need `mediaLink` to get the actual object data, and it's `getAuth` rather than `getIo`.

This script will output the file contents (given you have already initialised a `$client` object) :

```
$service = new Google_Service_Storage($client);
$object = $service->objects->get('bucketname', 'objectname');
$request = new Google_Http_Request($object->getMediaLink());
$response = $client->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($request);
echo $response->getResponseBody();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid for apiclient ~2.0, see [UPGRADING.md](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#google_auth_abstract-classes-have-been-removed) file in github.

Working code with apiclient ~2.0 should be:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Storage($client);
$object = $service->objects->get('bucketname', 'objectname');

// create an authorized HTTP client
$httpClient = $client->authorize();

$response = $httpClient->request('GET', $object->getMediaLink());

echo $response->getBody();
```

or authorizing an existing Guzzle client:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Storage($client);
$object = $service->objects->get('bucketname', 'objectname');

// add authorization to an existing client
$httpClient = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$httpClient = $client->authorize($httpClient);

$response = $httpClient->request('GET', $object->getMediaLink());

echo $response->getBody();
```

Answer (score -3):

for downloading file, you need grant READER access to allUsers (you can do it from google web console or use google php api)

Comment: No, you have to use signed urls, so users have time limited access to the files and only with the url. See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#Signed-URLs