# Downloading from google cloud storage with php

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-api-php-client

Is there a way to achieve downloading via. the google-php-api? I have tried the following:

- using the medialink and trying to curl the object (Returns "Login Required")
- reading the guzzle response stream (comes back empty even though all the headers have the correct data)

I am able to see everything but the body of the file via. the API.

Edit:

I am of course able to download the file via the medialink, taken it is set to public - however that will not work for this situation.

Comment: I'm having the same issue at the same time. I read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855705/downloading-files-using-google-api-php-client, but it appears the new Google PHP API does not use `Google_Http_Request` anymore.

Comment: @ObinwanneHill Thanks for pointing me there, this allowed me to figure out the rest! I have posted the answer with a code snippet of what you essentially need to do.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is as follows...

You must make an authorized HTTP request, to do this you must:

```
$object = $service->objects->listObjects(BUCKET, OBJECT);
$http = $client->authorize();
$request = new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', $object->getMediaLink());
$response = $http->send($request);
$body = $response->getBody()->read($object->getSize());
```

The above is a small snippet but the jist of what you need to get the contents of a file.

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the `$response->getBody()->read($object->getSize())` bit. Works great now